# Overflow vertical in a flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container with `height: 100%` and `display: flex`, with the children aligned left and bottom.

When the children are overflowing, I need to show the scrollbar, but also with `overflow: auto` it doesn't happen.

Here's a pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdWzPd

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added `justify-content` property, Then `overflow: scroll` won't work. Add one child div inside `flex-box` and give `overflow` property to that

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
    align-content: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #bebebe;
}
.inner_container{
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.box {
    align-self: flex-start;
    background: #e5e5ea none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    max-width: 80%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="inner_container">
    <div class="box">


  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur condimentum ornare urna eget ornare. In eget ornare velit, nec rhoncus lectus. Pellentesque vitae tortor tellus. Praesent elementum, nulla at porta elementum, lacus turpis tempus turpis, efficitur viverra libero turpis vel erat. Sed mollis lectus id libero volutpat tincidunt. Ut eleifend odio lectus, a vulputate arcu posuere id. Pellentesque laoreet enim vitae nibh eleifend porta. 
    </div>
    <div class="box">


  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur condimentum ornare urna eget ornare. In eget ornare velit, nec rhoncus lectus. Pellentesque vitae tortor tellus. Praesent elementum, nulla at porta elementum, lacus turpis tempus turpis, efficitur viverra libero turpis vel erat. Sed mollis lectus id libero volutpat tincidunt. Ut eleifend odio lectus, a vulputate arcu posuere id. Pellentesque laoreet enim vitae nibh eleifend porta. 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my updated **[codePen](http://codepen.io/syamsp1123/pen/OWJdyN?editors=1100)**

Comment: Yeah, I tried it before the question but with this the "width auto" is not working.

A solution is to create another div inside the box with the background, padding, max-width properties and a "display inline-block" to set the autowidth, but if there's a solution to avoid this it will be better.